# How to change the icon of a different .NET application dynamically (from C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on an installer and want the installer to have the same icon (on the Windows taskbar and in explorer) as the application it's installing.

I don't want to recompile the installer with a different icon each time, so how could the installer's icon be changed from another (C#) application (the installer creator app)?

Ideally, the icon could be pulled out of the .exe being installed if possible.

How could this be done?

Comment: What installer are you using exactly?  The installer projects that existed in previous version of Visual Studio are no longer supported in VS2012.  If you want the installer to use the icon your are going to have to compile the installer package, although the icon can be dynamic, it just needs to be compiled.

Comment: See [`Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon.aspx).

Comment: @Ramhound It's a custom installer (written from the ground up). Okay, how easy would it be to dynamically change the icon before compile (so the whole thing can remain automated).

Comment: @Ginosaji +1 Thanks, that solves part of my problem.

Comment: @James - You wrong your own software to handle installing your software?  That seems unlikely....

Comment: @Ramhound I have my own installer I have written, it's a winforms C# project and integrates some custom DRM - hence I can do what I like with it.